# Wrapping Japanese characters in web

Tags: word-wrap, cjk

I need to wrap Japanese characters or make it responsive on sidebar.

Here's my problem:

[image]

---

Below are the Japanese characters: 
部門①！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！

Already searched some of the questions related here (some are already closed and not solved).

Comment: You will have to provide a little more detail than *"web"* because the solution will likely depend on your specific platform. Please add the according language or platform tag and try to include a [mcve] reproducing your problem.

Comment: @Filburt can't edit the post need reputation. However, let's make it simple. In simple html, css, js.

Comment: You **always** can [edit] your own post. You only need 50 rep to comment on other peoples posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **word-break** CSS property like following example. "break-word" can break the continuous ！！！！ characters.

```
.side-bar {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

You can compare the behavior of "break-all" and "break-word" values in following CSS Demo section.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break